# how to call external web services in phonegap application

Tags: android, ajax, web-services, cordova, getjson

I am new to phonegap. I want to call server side web service from phonegap application to get data. I have tried it on browser it working fine and also on Phonegap developer app for Android. Both are working fine. But if i make .APK from PhonegapBuild console and installed on android device, it doesn't work anymore.
I have used AJAX to call web service. I also tried other solutions related this but all are fail.

**Solution 1:**

Changed in config.xml
`< access origin="*"/>` with

```
< access origin="http://mywebserviceipaddress"/>
```

**Solution 2:** Changed AJAX call with `.get()` method. For this added image where i have added two methods for code.

**Solution 3:** Added

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  crossDomain: true,
  async: false,
  cache : false,
  ...
  });
```

in AJAX call

Here is my both code. Please tell me if missing any parameters.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDBii.png)

Comment: Can you give us all your `config.xml` file ? Please do not post images but directly your code.

Comment: <widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="#appname" version="1.0.0"><br>
<access origin="http://my_ip_address*"/>
  <!-- <access origin="*"/> --> // Commented to test above line
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="tel:*" launch-external="yes" />
  <allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>

  ... Rest of things are common. Platform, Preference , Plugin. I havn't changed anything in it. Except for web service. To give access for other ip addresses.

</widget>

Comment: Was the phonegap app installed on the same device that you tested after ?

Comment: `< access origin="*"/>`should do the work.

Comment: Yes. I am thinking the same. But its not working. I have also referred some posts where they have mentioned it doesn't work sometimes. You have to add specific ip address which you want to access.